# textarea maxlength doesnot work on enter key press

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textarea which mas its maxlength set to 200 and it works. But if the user while enter the characters, hits enter and enters 199 characters of hits enter twice and then enters 198 chars, the textarea displays the message that max 200 characters should be entered.

This problem persists in IE but not in chrome

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are seeing is the difference in how Chrome and IE treat the enter key.

- Chrome treats the enter key as `\r\n` (two characters)
- IE treats the enter key as just `\n` (one character)

This is illustrated by this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AVje6/).

---

Results:

- Chrome

  ```
  1\r\n
  2\r\n
  3\r\n
  4\r\n
  5\r\n
  6\r\n
  78
  ```

> Note: You cannot press enter after the `7`, because it will count as 2 characters and exceed the max of 20, because the number 7 represents the 19th character.

- IE

  ```
  1\n
  2\n
  3\n
  4\n
  5\n
  6\n
  7\n
  8\n
  9\n
  10
  ```

Interestingly, jQuery treats the enter key as a single character too (`\n`), thus if you use jQuery to count for you, then you will end up with the same "problem" that IE has.